# I want to open a pop-up modal when the user click the URL

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I want to use a pop-up model for "Forgot my password".

The scenario is, a user clicks the "Forgot my password" button, the system then sends a URL to their email account. The user clicks that URL, it redirects them a "*Sign in*" page, once on the ***sign in page***, I want to open a pop-up for the user to create their new password.

The question is, how can I trigger the pop-up to only open up that URL, which was clicked before from users email account? There is no button to trigger that. How can i do that?

Comment: You can start by listening to the `$(document).ready(...)` event. Inside the function callback  you can invoke the modal. Remember that you didn't provide any code for us to look at. So that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

With `window.location.href` you can get the current url, and with this code you can check if some string contains in url, Do something:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("some-string-in-url") > -1) {
    alert("found it");
}
```